# Imagem Wordpress - Header customizada

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou criando um tema do zero no Wordpress, e gostaria de fazer, no cabeçalho, um background com uma imagem customizada. Estou tentando fazer no front-page.php mesmo.

Primeiro, que tentei acessar a imagem através do caminho:

*img/background.jpg*

E não deu certo. A princípio, adicionei a imagem na biblioteca. Recuperou todo o endereço como se estivesse upado, aí sim consegui adicionar a imagem através de um caminho específico.

Porém, como faço para customizar a imagem? Pois pretendo fazer o site responsivo, e preciso acessar, tanto a imagem, quando a div que a contorna.

O código:

front-page.php

```
<div class="header-image">
    <img src="enderecoDaImagem/background.jpg" alt="Roma" />
</div><!-- /header-image -->


<?php if (have_posts()) : 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        the_content();


        endwhile; 

        else : 

            echo '<p> Não tem Posts </p>';

        endif;  

?>
```

style.css

```
img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%; /*Isso faz com que a imagem não saia de dentro do wrapper.*/
    height: auto;
}

.header-image{
    border: 3px solid red;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Nem mesmo colocando uma border na classe ela é aplicada.

Ou seja, a imagem aparece, porém, não consigo customizar ela.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer dizer com "customizar a imagem"?

Comment: Deixar a imagem com um width:100%, por exemplo.

Ou aplicar uma borda nela.

De qualquer modo, gostaria de conseguir acessar esta imagem: _div.nomeClasse img_

Comment: Então é problema de CSS, apenas. Se a imagem está aparecendo, logo ela está sendo inserida no elemento, seja como background de uma DIV ou como elemento IMG. Dito isso, como está seu CSS?

Comment: Atualizei o post.

Comment: Não entendo seu problema. Seu código [funciona como esperado](http://jsfiddle.net/z0gnd5wz/) (apesar de o correto ser `.header-image img`, para não afetar as outras imagens do tema). Sendo assim, tem certeza de que o CSS está sendo requisitado junto com a página? Dá uma olhada no Inspetor de Redes do browser e veja se não não tem um 404 pro seu CSS.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno! De fato, não estava recuperando o CSS. Embora eu ainda não tenha testado especificamente o que quero, não estava mesmo recuperando o CSS.<br/>
Nas aulas, o professor criou a página _header.php_ para que pudesse ser incluso a folha de estilo. <br/>
Então ficou assim:<br/><br/>
_index.php ->(requisita)-> header.php ->(requisita) -> functions.php._ <br/>
O Wordpress tem a função **wp_header();**. Esta função requisita para a página _functions.php_. E dentro do _function.php_ tem-se a requisição da folha em cascata.